# PHP/GD : Getting a small white square on white background when creating any image

Tags: php, gd

I am starting on [php](/questions/tagged/php) and am trying to create an image using [php-gd](/questions/tagged/php-gd), but keep getting a weird output.

I am using [xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp).

Here's my code: (a black line should be seen into the screen)

```
<?php
    header ("Content-type: image/png");
    $image = imagecreate(200, 50);
    
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    
    ImageLine ($image, 30, 30, 120, 120, $black);
    imagepng($image);
?>
```

I tried with many samples found in the internet but i keep getting

[image], for **anything** I'm trying to do. (from showing text to creating a watermark). I use examples already tested by others, so the code isn't probably the problem.

Could you please say me what is wrong?

Edit : I am actually on the right window
(my file is stored at `C:\xampp\htdocs\projet_30_03_21\template.php`)

Edit : Ctrl+F5 doesn't work either. Also tried creating a new window.

Comment: But your output image is a square. The given example a rectangle image (200x50). Since your line start to 30px from the left. Increase the size of image or move your line.

Comment: @Syscall I tried with other shapes too, and got the same result; i even tried changing the background color, and got the exact same output.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Tried by putting `$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);` just before the black color definition : doesn't work either.

Comment: If `imagecreate` is not defined. Check your GD installation. The `header()` should be called just before `imagepng()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`imagefill()`](https://php.net/imagefill) to define a background before to add a black line, because the background is already black.

It's also recommanded to use [`imagecreatetruecolor()`](https://php.net/imagecreatetruecolor) instead of imagecreate().

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 50);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);
imageline($image, 30, 30, 120, 120, $black);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
```

Give the following image

[image]

Comment: Got `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreate() in C:\xampp\htdocs\projet_30_03_21\template.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projet_30_03_21\template.php on line 2` when trying this. When I put the header at the beginning of the file, i got the same black backdrop with white rectangle.

Comment: OK. That's the issue. GD is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem (https://www.php.net/manual/fr/install.windows.legacy.index.php#install.windows.legacy.building).
I had to uncomment this line of code :
`;extension=gd`
to
`extension=gd`.